# If statement MATLAB example issue

Tags: matlab, if-statement, output, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to run this simple if-statement MATLAB code on MATLAB 7.6.0 (R2008a) version.

*I typed this in M-File:

```
function output = DEMO(input)
 if input > 0
   fprintf('Greater than 0')
elseif input < 0
   fprintf('Less then 0')
else
   fprintf('Equals 0')
end

outvar = 1;
```

*Tried to implement it in command window:
Whenever I entered a number it always gives me Greater than 0!

As here: 
[image]

What's wrong? 
I could not figure it out? 
Is it because the outvar = 1? I tried to make it 0, got the same result! -.-

Comment: Yes, It gave me less than zero

Comment: But whay the ans is always one! is it because the outvar?

Comment: @ Mariah, yes that is why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a function the following way:

```
DEMO 0
```

This implicitly passes `0` as a *string*: `'0'`. When you perform a comparison between the string `'0'` and `0`, the `'0'` is converted to it's ASCII code (`32`) and it always appears to be greater than `0`.

Instead, you will want to use parentheses to explicitly call the function and pass a number.

```
DEMO(0)
```

As a side note, you seem to be assigning to `outvar` but then the output argument of your function is actually `output`. Also, you assign `outvar` to `1` at the bottom *regardless of the condition*. If you want a different output value for each condition, you need to set the output value *within* the `if` statement of interest.

Maybe something like:

```
function output = DEMO(input)
    if input > 0
       fprintf('Greater than 0')
       output = 1;
    elseif input < 0
       fprintf('Less then 0')
       output = -1;
    else
       fprintf('Equals 0')
       output = 0;
    end
end
```